# Github pages not loading css on subfolders

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll, github-pages

Any idea why github pages stoped loading css and images in subfolders, it works fine on the root of the site.

When i checked the source code of the page, i see this

```
"href="css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">"
```

instead of

```
"href="/css/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">".
```

In my config file I have a line

```
baseurl : /
```

--> `crowd42.github.io`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work the way it is `baseurl : "/"` if when loading assets you use that variable:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.baseurl}}css/main.css">
```

As it seems that you aren't using base urls, you can try forcing the root path with a slash at the beginning:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Or including the absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{'css/main.css'|absolute_url}}">
```

with `baseurl: ""`.